# How to Generate SCRAM-SHA-256 to Create Postgres 13 User

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-5

I want to create a Postgres user with the CREATE USER command and an already hashed digest for the password.  After much searching, I thought it was only possible with MD5 until I found [this](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781789537581/1/ch01lvl1sec18/changing-your-password-securely) link.  I've verified that works like so:

```
CREATE USER test_user WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:H45+UIZiJUcEXrB9SHlv5Q==$I0mc87UotsrnezRKv9Ijqn/zjWMGPVdy1zHPARAGfVs=:nSjwT9LGDmAsMo+GqbmC2X/9LMgowTQBjUQsl45gZzA=';
```

I can then log into that user with the password, which the article doesn't necessarily say but it's "postgres".  Now that I know it's possible, how using .NET 5 can I generate a scram-sha-256 digest that Postgres 13 will accept?  I've seen other Postgres articles using the outdated MD5 hash where the username is concatenated with the password before hashing.  Does that need to happen with the new scram-sha-256 as well?  I couldn't find much information on this topic anywhere.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but here is a link which describes the SCRAM password string in more detail: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/catalog-pg-authid.html
(see bottom of that page). Also I guess you could look at the PostgreSQL source code to find out how the password gets encrypted when setting a password with the `\password` command or when creating a user with `createuser someuser --login --pwprompt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how to generate a scram-sha-256 digest with .NET 5.
However, if the scram-sha-256 digest is all you need you can use a workaround by creating a dummy postgres user locally and echoing the encryped password with the `createuser` command.

For example (usually you run this as Linux postgres user: `su postgres`):

```sh
$ createuser dummyuser -e --pwprompt
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
CREATE ROLE dummyuser PASSWORD 'SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:VnimR0aOywxZzY82nzy9Fg==$qF9uMCU6YsKoecvRjP8jSmZZxrXgn5VwzhHwfoWo5Xg=:xGYfBUvGsu9mZFiq1nSFaHi7uN8n47IDwHO32IeK9io=' NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;
```

You can now just copy the digest into your query. Of course that only works if you don't need to generate the digest dynamically with .NET.

Don't forget to drop the dummy user:

```sh
$ dropuser dummyuser
```

Also, in case your local postgres db still uses/generates md5 you have to change that to scram by using following query, ran as postgres superuser:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET password_encryption = 'scram-sha-256';
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

If you, however, want to create the digest dynamically with .NET, I recommend you to have a look at the source code of the `createuser` command...

**Update one day later:**

Here is the specific source code of the `createuser` command that encrypts the password into a scram-sha-256 string:

- https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/6beb38cfc9ddd4cd3d2eb5402981ebdd69a618b4/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-auth-scram.c#L884-L921

To make life easier, here are links to the functions (probably not all) the above function is calling

- https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/6beb38cfc9ddd4cd3d2eb5402981ebdd69a618b4/src/common/saslprep.c#L1023-L1245
- https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/6beb38cfc9ddd4cd3d2eb5402981ebdd69a618b4/src/common/scram-common.c#L160-L274

You should be able to rewrite that code in .NET or any other language. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right and was thinking that I might have to go that route at this point too.  There's not an abundance of SASL libs in C# that I'm excited about using.  The nice thing is the source code that you linked has all of the Unicode normalization invalid characters in one place, and I was trying to list out all of them from the [RFC3454 docs page](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3454).  That was quickly becoming a nightmare.  The only thing I'm wondering about is if I actually need to do all of this if I'm using Postgres SSL and my database server isn't public facing.

Comment: I may just be adding layers of security and creating unnecessary work for myself.  I'll need to think on it, but if I do port it to C#, I'll make the code available for others.

Answer (score 9):

Someone built a Go tool to do this:

https://github.com/supercaracal/scram-sha-256

Here's a python 3 port based on that Go project:

```
from base64 import standard_b64encode
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac, sha256
from os import urandom
import hmac
import sys


salt_size = 16
digest_len = 32
iterations = 4096


def b64enc(b: bytes) -> str:
    return standard_b64encode(b).decode('utf8')


def pg_scram_sha256(passwd: str) -> str:
    salt = urandom(salt_size)
    digest_key = pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', passwd.encode('utf8'), salt, iterations,
                             digest_len)
    client_key = hmac.digest(digest_key, 'Client Key'.encode('utf8'), 'sha256')
    stored_key = sha256(client_key).digest()
    server_key = hmac.digest(digest_key, 'Server Key'.encode('utf8'), 'sha256')
    return (
        f'SCRAM-SHA-256${iterations}:{b64enc(salt)}'
        f'${b64enc(stored_key)}:{b64enc(server_key)}'
    )


def print_usage():
    print("Usage: provide single password argument to encrypt")
    sys.exit(1)


def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]

    if args and len(args) > 1:
        print_usage()

    if args:
        passwd = args[0]
    else:
        passwd = sys.stdin.read().strip()

    if not passwd:
        print_usage()

    print(pg_scram_sha256(passwd))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**NOTE**: Passing passwords directly on the command line can leak secrets into shell history, make secrets visible in process output to other users on the system, etc. If you are using this tool to generate real password hashes, take care to protect it from such leakage (e.g. write the plain text password to a text file with secure permissions and redirect it to the script's input using `python scram256.py < secret-password.txt`). Also take care to use non-reused randomly generated passwords of sufficient length and other best practices that are beyond the scope of this question/answer.

Comment: Passing password as command line arguments is poor security practice, as it's most likely stored as plain text on disk in shell history file.

Comment: You can write the secret to a file with proper permissions and then `python scram.py < secure-password-file.txt` to avoid the security concern. My answer does not say to pass the secret as a cli arg.

Comment: It's not about what you "can" do. Users will take the easy, most obvious path, which is to pass the password as arg. You should protect users by making the obvious use-case safe. I highly suggest you edit your response to only accept file paths or only accept standard input.

Comment: It's great to warn inexperienced devs against bad practices and I added a note to that effect. However, it would not be appropriate to introduce limitations and muddying code based on usage assumptions. Users could disable shell history on a secure machine, pipe values in via std input, use the script in a toy environment where security is not a concern, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to generate a SCRAM-SHA-256 password *before* you have an operational database, then I found out you can use this method to generate a password hash using Docker tooling.

```
docker run --rm -it --name postgres-dummy -d -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres:14-alpine
docker exec -it postgres-dummy psql -U postgres
 \password
 (type in your password twice)
 select rolpassword from pg_authid where rolname = 'postgres';
 \q
docker stop postgres-dummy
```

I know it's not a way to do it in .NET, but hopefully it is useful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and I ended up delving into the Npgsql code and combining it with Shane's answer to come up with this. It's not exactly battle-hardened, but I did manage to create a role with it, and then subsequently log in with it. I prefer F#, but it's not too hard to convert this back to C#. Just remember that, in F#, the value of the last line of a function is the return value of that function. Also, in F#, ^^^ is the bitwise-xor operator.

```
let password_hash (password: string) =
    let normalized = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password.Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormKC))
    let salt_len = 16
    let default_iterations = 4096

    let salt = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(salt_len)
    let mutable salt1 = Array.create (salt.Length + 4) 0uy

    let hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(normalized)
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, salt1, 0, salt.Length)
    salt1[salt1.Length - 1] <- 1uy

    let mutable hi = hmac.ComputeHash(salt1)
    let mutable u1 = hi

    for _ in 1 .. default_iterations - 1 do
        let u2 = hmac.ComputeHash(u1)
        for i in 0 .. hi.Length - 1 do
            hi[i] <- hi[i] ^^^ u2[i]
        u1 <- u2

    let client_key = (new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(hi)).ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Client Key"))
    let stored_key = (System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create()).ComputeHash(client_key)
    let server_key = (new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(hi)).ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Server Key"))

    let builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder()
    builder.Append("'SCRAM-SHA-256$").Append(default_iterations.ToString()).Append(":").Append(System.Convert.ToBase64String(salt)).Append("$")
        .Append(System.Convert.ToBase64String(stored_key)).Append(":").Append(System.Convert.ToBase64String(server_key)).Append("'").ToString()
```