# Example psql command for pgbouncer connect with SCRAM-SHA-256 and multiple DBs

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

What would be a valid example psql command for connecting to pgbouncer in case of valid auth_file:

```
"testuser" "SCRAM-SHA-256......blablaExample"
```

For the following conf:

```
auth_type=scram-sha-256
...
[databases]
targetdb = host=1.1.1.1 dbname=testdb port=5432 user=testuser password=testpw
alternativedb = host=2.2.2.2 dbname=testdb port=5432 user=testuser password=testpw
```

Comment: Your auth_type value is missing a hyphen.

Comment: @jjanes Sorry. That was a mistake on me writing the question. In reality I had it like I edited question now.

Comment: I figured out that the psql command I need is:

`psql -U testuser -d targetdb --host=1.1.1.1 --port=5432`

But I haven't figured out why these SCRAM hash creation examples aren't working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400120/how-to-generate-scram-sha-256-to-create-postgres-13-user

Comment: Can I use SCRAM to only authenticate connection to pgbouncer and login from pgbouncer to postgres server via password in [databases] list?

Comment: The pgbouncer documentation suggests you can set a password in the `[databases]` section connection string, but as far as I can tell this doesn't actually work.

Comment: It only doesn't work in certain circumstances.  I reported a bug.  https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
psql -U testuser -d targetdb --host=pgbouncerip --port=5432
psql -U testuser -d sourcedb --host=pgbouncerip --port=5432
```

Comment: pgbouncer default port to listen is 6432, it is unclear from your config on which port you have configured pgboucer to listen. but since you have answered your own question i believe pgbouncer is listening on port 5432.

`port=5432` in your pgbouncer.ini signifies that your postgres is listening on 5432 as well. It's a good idea that you configure your database to listen on some other port that 5432 and then configure pgbouncer to listen on 5432 to avoid surprises

Comment: continued from my previous comment. if you have used default settings then the command should look like `psql -U testuser -d sourcedb --host=pgbouncerip --port=6432`